# How can I make a GET request in Ember with a '/' in the path?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to make a GET request to my backend application with Ember.js. The problem I'm having is that I have a '/' in the URL for the GET request. The URL I need to make a GET request to looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/alertsettings/settingId
```

But when I pass in the settingId as a parameter, like this:

```
this.store.find('alertsettings', {'settingId': settingId})
```

The resulting URL it tries to make the GET request to looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/alertsettings?settingId=12345
```

Does anyone know how to make a GET request to my backend application with the URL as described in the first codeblock (so '?settingId=12345' is replaced with '/12345')?

I am working with Ember v1.13. The code looks like this:

```
var promiseAlerts;
promiseAlerts = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  var websiteId = _this.get('session').get('websiteId');
  console.log(websiteId);
  _this.store.find('alertsetting', websiteId).then(function (data) {
    console.log("data", data);
    controller.set('alertsetting', data.content);
    resolve(data);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    reject(error);
  });
});
promises.push(promiseAlerts);
```

Comment: Where is this being called from? `findRecord` returns a promise there's no need to wrap it with another promise

Comment: When removing the surrounding promise, I get the following error: `Assertion Failed: Expected an object as data in a call to push for dataqit-front@model:alertsetting: , but was undefined`. It is called in the setupcontroller BTW

Comment: Can you put the entire route?

Comment: I have put it in a Github Gist [link](https://gist.github.com/Meikrekel/36a461a5081a9cfd0b38f448b64e27d6)

Comment: Can you join the [slack community](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com) there's too much to address here

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [findRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord), find was [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html).

`this.store.findRecord('alertsettings', settingId);` will do the trick.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm working with Ember version 1.13.. Added it to the first post. Your solution doesn't seem to work in Ember 1.13. Even simply trying to console log a test when I'm running this.store.findRecord doesn't work.

Comment: What errors are you getting and can you add context? Where are you calling findRecord and how are you accessing it's response? @WouterStolk

Comment: Remove the code from the comment and add it to the question